# Running .NET 1.1 on Windows Azure

Tags: .net, asp.net, azure

Is it possible to run ASP.NET 1.1 on the Windows Azure?

Thanks!

Comment: @john, when using services/libraries that require it - eg Web Services Enhancements - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=fc5f06c5-821f-41d3-a4fe-6c7b56423841

Comment: @Chris: Why would you want to run WSE? At all? Anywhere? It's quite obsolete.

Comment: @John - agreed very much, unfortunately, the server/vendor we are talking to is running it - so either we re-write the WSE client in WCF or use WSE.  I guess the WSE standards never took off, but our vendor missed the memo :(

Comment: @Chris: I suppose that I have been fortunate that I have not needed to work for fools very often.

Comment: @John LOL - got any jobs going :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no.  It's almost strange to me that they're even targeting .NET 3.5, since they went live so close to the .NET 4 release date.  I guess it's because .NET 3.5 is so well tested.